# How do I compile using javac in command line this small code snippet

Tags: java, bash, javac

I am learning springframework and I don't want to use any IDE, and I want to work in java in pure command line in bash. I already have downloaded lots of jar I can see them in /root/.m2/repository as well as in /usr/share/maven/ref/repository/ too. The `AppConfig.java` i want to compile has the below content:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    // this is all there is
}
```

It compiles fine without the `@Configuration` annotation. At the top of my head, I know that I need to pull-in the correct jar. To be systematic in future dealings of these things, I want to know how to:

- Identify the correct jar and location of jar needed for a keyword

I accept maven pom.xml way of doing things if needed, but if possible I want to work in the most minimal way.

Comment: _"I am learning springframework and I don't want to use any IDE"_ -- This is an unwise choice.  There is too much happening in terms of dependencies and organization to be effective without an IDE to manage things for you.  Your statement is like saying "I want to learn woodworking but use only stone tools". Is it possible? Yes. Will you be able to produce anything of any complexity or functionality? No.

Comment: Alright. I will relax the requirements and willing to use maven pom.xml. How about that? To me, the IDE is hiding a lots of things... just my observation. These scaffolding can be automated in command line just like how angular-cli is... etc...

Comment: It is much easier to use a build tool like maven or gradle that will keep track of the dependencies for you. You are then still not using an IDE.

Comment: What do you have against IDEs? Don't you want the help and guidance an IDE provides, to improve the speed of writing code, because you spend less time looking at javadocs, and find and fix errors faster, at the very least? --- Why even allow use of text editors, like `vi` or `nano`? You can edit files using [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). Sure it's cumbersome, but you can make any changes you want. Use the tools available to you, to improve your productivity.

Comment: i would strongly suggest using maven or gradle for this. If you sdtill want to use javac, you need to use javac -cp <list of jar dependecies> ...

Comment: IDE "hide" a lot of stuff, but it's stuff that is tedious boilerplate, and there's nothing stopping you from investigating what happens under the covers.  Your productivity will be about 10-20x higher with an IDE, if only because of the instant syntax checking, completion and refactoring tools. Take it from someone who started on punched cards (so I know what "no IDE" means quite well), I would not work without an IDE for any amount of money.  My time and sanity are worth more than that to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real non answer: don't do that.

For a complete newbie just starting with Java it can be beneficial to first do all work himself - using only a text editor and javac manually. Because that teaches you a lot of things.

But: the spring framework is nothing that Java newbies should start with. And when you are more experienced, you stop doing all things manually. Then you rather focus on using all the tools that are around to make your life easier. Thus: when working with spring - use an IDE and a build system such as maven or grade. Because sprint itself adds (several) ordes of magnitude of complexity.

Like in: when you start as an architect, you might use a shovel yourself to dig the basement for your garden house. But as soon as you intend to do "real work", you forget about the shovel and start using excavators.